# Why Fluent Interface is called Fluent API

Tags: design-patterns, definition, ef-fluent-api, fluent-interface

Why Fluent API is called "API" ? Fluent API is a way to create fluent Domain Specific Language, whereas API is "Appication Programming Interface". API is:

"A set of functions and procedures that allow the creation of applications which **access** the features or data of an **operating system, application, or other service**."

"An application programming interface (API) is a set of protocols, routines, functions and/or commands that programmers use to develop software or facilitate **interaction between distinct systems**."

So how this two definitions containing words "Distinct system", "Access features" relate to Fluent Interface pattern? 
Even Martin Fowler sometimes names it API:
https://martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html

Please, tell me, what's wrong with my or other's idea about API? Maybe we should stop calling screwdrivers all long metal rods with handles?

Comment: Can’t you use Fluent APIs to access features of a distinct system?

Answer (score 1):

In the given definitions of API, I think the operative word both times is ***or***.

> - ...***or*** other service.
> - ...***or*** facilitate interaction between distinct systems.

This is explicitly *not* saying that to "*facilitate interaction between distinct systems*" is a requirement of an API. You can pick any one of the choices in each list and call it an API. For example, an API could be,

- A set of functions and procedures that allow the creation of applications which access the data of an application.
- A set of functions and commands that programmers use to develop software.

All I did here is choose an option from each list with the word *or*. As you can see, the definition of API is very abstract. In short, every method signature is an API.